# How to set logs/prints for apache beam pipeline running on Direct Runner with python

Tags: python, logging, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I can not display logs or prints when coding in python, apache beam pipelines using a direct runner.

```
import logging

class PrintFn(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        print(element)
         logging.error(element)
        return [element]
```

---

```
def run(argv=None):
    lines = p | 'receive_data' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(
            subscription=known_args.in_topic).with_input_types(str) \
            | 'decode' >> beam.Map(lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')) \
            | 'jsonload' >> beam.Map(lambda x: json.loads(x)) \
            |'print' >> beam.ParDo(PrintFn())
```

Comment: The standard Python logging library is the correct way to perform logging in Apache Beam pipelines. Are you missing a call to p.run()? What (if any) output do you get when you run your python program?

Comment: As Lukasz pointed out, you're likely missing a `p.run()`. Your pipeline should be showing output.